# proof of substitution rule for riemann intergration

Tags: real-analysis

Prove: let $J:=[\alpha, \beta]$ and let $\phi:J \to \mathbf{R}$ have a continuous derivative on $J$. If $f:I \to \mathbf{R}$ is continuous on an interval $I$ containing $\phi(J)$, then $\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f(\phi(t))\phi'(t)dt=\int_{\phi(\alpha)}^{\phi(\beta)}f(x)dx$.

attempt:

consider $f\circ\phi:J\to \mathbf{R}$ then derivative of that is $f'(\phi(x))\phi'(x)$ then I'm stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Try the same with $\displaystyle F(y) =\int_{\varphi(\alpha)}^y f(t) \, dt$ in place of $f$.